# Javascript/JQuery - Running Code Dynamically Some Time After Page Load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with running some javascript code, the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hidesolutions()
    {
        $('.optiondiv').hide();
    }
    hidesolutions()
</script>
```

The flow is:

HTML page loads
User clicks a button
Javascript function runs & Calls a PHP script that outputs data to the page
Javascript function finishes
PHP script finishes

The PHP script outputs a div with class "optiondiv" that I want to hide as soon as the PHP is done. I cannot hide it in the javascript that runs when the button is clicked as this finishes before the PHP is done.

Essentially I'm trying to insert the above script into the HTML at some random point in time, but obviously this means it does not run, so I've tried echoing it out in the PHP - does not work and I've tried putting it in the javascript, but unfortunately the javascript finishes before the PHP does and does not find anything to hide.

EDITED to make clearer as per comments.

Comment: `.click();`, google "jquery click".

Comment: If you want the content to load before hiding the button, use `.ajax();` as ryanmarc suggested on the `click();` event and hide your div in the `success: ` AJAX success function. `$('.optiondiv').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({ // insert AJAX options here }); });`

Comment: Are you pulling in the content through an ajax call when you click the a button?  If so, sounds like you need to fire off this function in the success callback of that ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using ajax to pull in your data from the php file.  You'll need to call this function in the success callback of your ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I'm just using plan Javascript to update the page. Someone clicks a button, calls a javascript functions, calls a php script that outputs lots of data. But I think the javascript finishes before the PHP does. Is there some way I can make something run on completion of the PHP, as the stuff I want to hide comes out of the PHP itself.

Comment: Can you add to your question with some code of what you're doing to get the info from php?  Yes, there are ways to know when the info has finished loading, but there's not enough info to answer that in regards to what you're doing.